# python: how to shuffle matrix rows according to a list of numbers

Tags: python, numpy, shuffle, numpy-ndarray

I have this numpy array `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5; 6, 7, 8, 9, 10; 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ]` and a list of numbers [0, 2, 1]. I want to shuffle `a`'s rows according to the list of numbers in a way that `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5; 11, 12, 13, 14, 15; 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. Is there a way to do it without creating a new numpy array for the result?

Comment: What's up with the semi-colons inside your array?

Comment: Is your array one or two-dimensional?

Comment: two dimensional. sorry I don't know how to write down matrix here

Comment: You'd write it the same as you would create a two-dimensional array. See liuyu's answer for an example of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
a[:] = a[[0,2,1]]
```